# UITableViewCell subviews not getting initialized

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, subview

I have a TableViewController and have designed a custom uitableview cell using storyboard.I have set Identifiers and tags for all the subview in my tableview cell correctly (I am not doing this for the first time and have generally got things working easily).

But now I have been observing some weird things on my tableview controller. in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, I am getting the proper cell. I am also able to access my subviews with tags. But when I try to access the frame properties of any of the subviews, I am getting value 0.

Do the subviews get laid out later in some other method. This is first time I am seeing this. Has someone experienced this before?

Comment: add some code for reference

Answer (score 3):

The the cell's subview frames are only ready after the `UITableViewCell` 'layoutSubviews' method has been called. If you need to modify these frames, then you should create a subclass of UITableViewCell and implement layoutSubviews

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
  [super layoutSubviews];

  // modify frames here
}
```

If you only need to access the frames values and do not need to do any changes, then you can simply check that in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: Well said, other @Matt! Just to be clear, should point out that `layoutSubviews` is even later than `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: I did check the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: ' and even over there frame dimensions are still zero. I do not need to modify the frame but I am constructing another view based on the this frame size. I guess I will Subclass it. But weird thing is I have another table view in my storyboard with similar views and there I subview is getting initialized in the cellForIndexPath method itself. Thanks Matt(s.. :)) for the help!

Comment: Are the subviews you're checking the frames of displaying correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Implement `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` and check the frames of the subviews there. Are they okay there? Then all is well.